# git terminal show "rebase" next to branch name

Tags: git

I'm very new to git and I don't know how I did it, or why it's showing this on my terminal, but when I open git terminal (from sourcetree) I see the branch name like this:

```
c:/my/project/folder (develop|REBASE-i 1/13)
```

What is causing this? And how can I remove this? I remember that before it used to show just the branche name `(develop)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are in a middle of rebasing so either do

```
git rebase --continue
```

or:

```
git rebase --abort
```

Comment: I didn't noticed this until today. Your answer solved the issue. But now my develop branch is way back in the history. Is there a way to bring to the last commit i have?

Comment: ```git pull``` Please read about basics of git here https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Answer (score 3):

You can see about this problem in [documentation the Git](https://git-scm.com/doc) but now you can **run this following command in `Gitbash`** :

```
git rebase --abort
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below command if you don't have any idea how to proceed.

> git rebase --quit